# Does a Cocomplete Cowellpowered Additive Category have Generator?

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Cocomplete Cowellpowered additive category. Does  $\mathcal{C}$ need to have a generator?

Comment: I've deleted all the inappropriate tags (monoidal categories? higher category theory? ...). The short answer to your question is *No*. The long answer should construct, of course, a pathological counterexample ...

Comment: Thank you Martin.
Could you tell me where I could find a counterexample for it? I am working on a project and I really need it.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a proper class and let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of families $\{A_i: i\in I\}$ of abelian groups indexed by $I$ such that $\{j\in I:A_j\neq0\}$ is a set.

Comment: Or equivalently, the (directed) union $\bigcup_{\kappa \ge 0} \textbf{Ab}^\kappa$. Note that this is an abelian category!

Comment: @ZhenLin: And complete. And well-powered. And (if you do it with vector spaces instead of abelian groups) semisimple. Come to think of it, it's hard to imagine a less pathological category! :-)